# How to find the distance travelled by user without using GPS

Tags: ios, accelerometer, distance, core-motion

i am doing one application.In that I want to find how much distance travelled by user.And i don't want to use the GPS due to battery drain.In some posts i saw,they are using Accelerometer to find the distance with different formulae.But didn't understand that posts.And that accelerometer giving the accelerate data when the device is in stationary mode also.So how to calculate the distance travelled by user.

Comment: Significant Location Changes is a lightweight GPS consumer, you can use that.

Comment: Already i am using location manager  with startupdatinglocation for every one minute.